# MVC3 - Model set to null but still entering IF statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement, model

I have a Model (BusinessPlaceDetailsViewModel) which has another Model (Hub) inside it.

However if I set my Hub to null it still enters my IF condition, see here:

[image]

I have tried loads of different combinations like putting each IF statement inside its own braces.

Why is it entering the If block?

Comment: Could you show your model? Especially how is the `Hub` property defined.

Comment: public HubViewModel Hub { get; set; }

Comment: @Scottie his screenshot shows Hub is null

Comment: You hightlighted code at the breakpoint looks a little weird to me - I wonder if you are debugging a page that is out of sync with the compiled version? I think I would unload your dev server or restart IIS Express (depending on what you are using), rebuild, and rerun the debug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that it is a problem with the controller not passing the model down to the view.

If you post the controller code it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, can you try this and see if the `h1` displays?

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    if (Model.Hub == null)
    {
        <h1>wtf shouldn't have gotten here</h1>
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you handle your check in the controller first?  If not maybe try .Any() with Ling.

```
 @using System.Linq


 @if( !Model.Any() )
 {
     ...
 }
 else
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the following in the BusinessPlaceDetailsViewModel

```
public BusinessPlaceDetailsViewModel()
{
   Hub = new HubViewModel();
}
```